# Laravel Auth Filter and Logout

Tags: php, authentication, filter, logout, laravel

I am developing a website in laravel. I am facing a problem with the auth filter and the logout method.

In my home controller I want to apply the auth filter for some of the methods as follows.

```
public function __construct()
{
     parent::__construct(); 
     $this->filter('before',array('auth'))->except(array('index','view'));
}
```

I have action_logout as follows.

```
public function action_logout() 
{
    Auth::logout();
    return Redirect::to("/home/index");
}
```

When I have logged in and trying to logout, i am not being able to access the logout action. I tried echoing something from the inside of the action but it didnt work.

changing to this..

```
$this->filter('before',array('auth'))->except(array('index','view','logout'));
```

works. Logically I should be able to logout only when i have logged in. But applying the filter above m not being able to access the logout action after loggin in. Help!.

Comment: Works without problems here. Maybe some more details?

Comment: Sorry.. Actually there was a problem in nesting the checking condition. Fix that problem. Now It's working nice.